# sidekiq share variable between threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, sidekiq

Rails 5.0.1, Ruby 2.4.0, Sidekiq 4.2.9

I need count some specific data in background jobs. I implemented it already through Postgres, but I faced with problem: Sidekiq concurrency very loads DB connections and if I decrease concurrency number, jobs runing take a lot time.

I found that it's possible to use atomic counter and in some period save result to DB.

So can I share variable between threads in Sidekiq? If it is, how I should initialize shared variable?

Thanks for any advise

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what information you actually want to share between sidekiq jobs?

Comment: I just should store count of some data, and when this count get limit, I should ignore job and stop processing

Comment: Using redis would make the most sense

Comment: You can use `Thread.get_thread_variable` but that will only work if you run Sidekiq on a single machine (and a single process)

Answer (score 2):

If you share a variable between threads, you need to worry about locking it with a Mutex and it only scales to a single process.

Instead, use Redis commands to increment counters.

https://redis.io/commands/incr

Comment: so, it is a bad idea to use Mutex. Right?

Comment: Well you loose the benefit that sidekiq give you with is multithreading.

Comment: I didn't say it's a bad idea to use a Mutex.  I didn't say it's a good idea either.

Comment: Essentially, if you want concurrency and there is a mutex locking the shared data, then you no longer get concurrency.

Comment: This, unfortunately does not answer the initial question. May be people are looking for something to be shared and they end up seeing answer "do not use global variables, use redis".